# Conversion of class variable to method argument in recursive program

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have solved the leetcode problem to find [Sum of left leaves](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-left-leaves) in a tree with this code. I know using class vairables as a temp varible in recursion is a not good practice and some how the temp result need to be passed as the method argument. In this case I want to avoid using the class variable `sum` and make helper method `sumOfLeftLeaves(TreeNode root,TreeNode parent,int sum)` with additional argument. Please suggest me how to modify method. I tried different ways to do it but getting struck with returning the values.

```
//Find sum of all left nodes in a binary tree.    
public class Solution {
        //Class variable to capture sum
        int sum = 0;
        public int sumOfLeftLeaves(TreeNode root) {
             sumOfLeftLeaves(root,null);
             return sum;
        }

        public void sumOfLeftLeaves(TreeNode root,TreeNode parent){
            if(root != null){
                sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left,root);
                //If the node is a leaft node and it is left node to the parent
                if(root.left == null && root.right == null && (parent != null && parent.left == root)){
                    sum += root.val;
                }
                sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right,root);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Always define a recursive problem in terms of simpler versions of itself.

Call the function LL.

Base cases: LL( empty ) ≡ 0, LL( left leaf node ) ≡ node.val, LL( right leaf node ) ≡ 0

Inductive case: given LL( node.left ) and LL( node.right ) -> LL( node ) ≡ LL( node.left ) + LL( node.right )

```
public int sumOfLeftLeavesAux( TreeNode node, boolean flgIsLeftChild ) {
    // base case: empty tree
    if ( node == null )
        return 0;
    // base case: leaf node
    if ( node.left == null && node.right == null )
        return flgIsLeftChild ? node.val : 0;
    // inductive case
    return sumOfLeftLeavesAux( node.left, true ) + sumOfLeftLeavesAux( node.right, false );
}
```